# Installing Cordova in my computer windows 10

Tags: git, cordova

i m trying to install Cordova  using this command  :

```
npm install -g cordova
```

after adding to the PATH variable in System section the path of git installation  . In command line, it It said that 'npm' is not recognized as an internal command .. Need help, .. please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install node and it will install npm as well with it.

Download the installer from here:
https://nodejs.org/en/

`npm` is the NodeJS Package manager and its being installed along side with NodeJs.

Watch this movie to learn bit more about it:
https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm

Comment: thanks , it works but is it normal that npm takes a long time to install packages and nothing appears in command line?

Comment: And yo will net to set up proxy if yo need one